# Application insight configuration for spring boot is not working

Tags: spring-boot, azure-application-insights

> I am using **spring boot version 2.0.0**.
>   and I am using **applicationInsight-web and core jar 2.1.0**.
>   I have put **instrumantation key** in applicaionInsight.xml also.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-java-get-started#4-add-an-http-filter
It shows how to configure Application Insights Java SDK for SpringBoot Applications.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the configurations for me to make Spring-cloud + Azure Application Insight.

pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>applicationinsights-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0-BETA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>applicationinsights-logging-logback</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-BETA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentracing.brave</groupId>
            <artifactId>brave-opentracing</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

and dependenciesManagement

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0.RC5</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

logback-spring.xml

```
<appender name="aiAppender"
           class="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.logback.ApplicationInsightsAppender">
        <instrumentationKey>YOUR_INSTRUMENTATION_KEY</instrumentationKey>
</appender>
```

application.yml

```
azure:
  application-insights:
    instrumentation-key: YOUR_INSTRUMENTATION_KEY
```

Good luck!